# I want to centre the unity camera to the top right corner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created this code to move the camera half its width right and half its height up to make the top right the new centre, it did not work, where did I go wrong?

```
Camera.main.transform.position=Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector2((float)0.5,(float)0.5));
```

This is 2d mode by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `0.5, 0.5` is literally the center of the Viewport!

`0,0` is the bottom left corner and `1, 1` the top right.

You probably would rather do e.g.

```
Camera.main.transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(Vector2.one);
```

---

Btw just s general hint: Instead of `(float)0.5` you would rather directly use `0.5f` ;)

Comment: I did solve this, however why would I use 0.5f? is that the same thing or different?

Comment: `0.5f` **is** a `float` value! `0.5` is a `double` -> another numeric type. In Unity everything is based on `float` precision so there is no reason why to first define a `double` and then cast it to `float` .. especially if it is not about high precision (for a `0.5` even `half` would already be enough ;) => you are just creating 8byte more trash for the Garbage Collector ;)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to change the `viewport rect`. In Unity editor, in the inspector, select your camera, and change `viewport rect` to `x: 0.5`, `y: 0.5`, `w: 0.5`, `h: 0.5`. Changing the position only changes the world-space position of the camera (e.g. moving it to the right when mario moves to the right).

edit:
Okay so to do it in code

```
Camera.main.rect = new Rect(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
```

edit:edit:
To explain further, you set x and y to 0.5 to move it half the screen width and and half the screen height. Then you set width and height to 0.5 to also make them half the screen width and height. If you intended to have the camera centered on the top right but for some reason extend off the screen as well, you would leave width and height at 1.

Comment: No, I do mean to move the camera, this is not what I want to do. I want the same camera size, and I want the new middle to be where the top right corner was.

Comment: Oh I figured out what I need to do, in my original code where I put 0.5 and 0.5 they need to change to 1 and 1. Thanks anyway